# Prove or disprove: $L^n=M^n\nRightarrow L=M$ where $L$ and $M$ are languages

Tags: formal-languages

In a homework assignment, it's asked

> For any alphabet $\Sigma$; for all languages $L$, $M$ on $\Sigma$
> Prove that $\forall n>1$, $L^n=M^n\nRightarrow L=M$

The student and I tried in vain to make a proof for $n=2$ by exhibiting distinct $L$ and $M$ with $L^2=M^2$; so much that I now think the statement may be wrong. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $\Sigma^*$ and $\Sigma^*\setminus\{11\}$?

Comment: That's marvelous, it works!